# How to use vagrant box to create AWS EC2 instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, vagrant

I am developing in Laravel using Laravel Homestead vagrant box bud didn't have any production environment. Now I instructed to use AWS EC2 for production.

So is there any convenient way to get an AWS EC2 instance ready (Identical) to Laravel Homestead virtual box? I googled about it but didn't get any answer.

I tried to install dependencies by hand at EC2 instance. But it looks like lot of work and error prone, and there might be differences in production and local environment doing so?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel created Forge to do just this. See:

http://mattstauffer.co/blog/getting-your-first-site-up-and-running-in-laravel-forge

Downside... it costs $10 a month

You could try something like this, but I don't know if that will work with Homestead out of the box

http://www.iheavy.com/2014/01/16/how-to-deploy-on-amazon-ec2-with-vagrant/